# What is the approach when binding a large number of fields to a view

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, xaml

Through a lot of great help - I have been able to populate a xaml view with two fields from an SQLite database.  I am building this view/app, simply to aid my understanding about databinding.  I now would like to know two things.  The primary question, is this:

If I had 50 fields on the view - would I still use the same layout that I have used in this example?

And secondly,

Not that I am unhappy with this layout (not at all), but is there a better way to do it?

C# code

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Activity act = new Activity();
      SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(ClsVariables.StrDb);
      con.Open();
      var sqlText =string.Format("SELECT [Activity_Category], [Activity_Category_Sub] FROM tblActivity WHERE [ActivityID] = 1;");
      var sqlCmd = new SQLiteCommand(sqlText, con);
      using (var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          if (reader.Read())
          {
              act.Activity_Category = reader["Activity_Category"] as string;
              act.Activity_Category_Sub = reader["Activity_Category_Sub"] as string;
          }
      }
      con.Close();

      this.DataContext = act;
}
```

XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="TM.frmEdit"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Add/Edit/Delete" Height="195" Width="500" ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered">
    <Grid Name="GridMain">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Activity_Category}" Height="26" Margin="10,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Activity_Category_Sub}" Height="26" Margin="10,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: When you say "layout", are you referring to the design of your code?

Comment: Sorry - I'm primarily interested in knowing if the approach that I am using is the right one (of if there is a better way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) There are better ways to make queries that creating a sql string in code. Have a look at EntityFramework. This will simplify your life as you'll be dealing with strongly typed class objects rather than magic (and fragile) strings. It will also simplify your reliance on `Reader` and having to populate properties one field at a time, which isn't scalable.
 Just search for 'entityframework sqlite' for info.

(2) Have a look at MVVM as a design pattern, if you want to embrace data binding even further. As terry said, it will help you shape your data and not rely on raw 'as it is in the table' representations. I disagree with him about what is a ViewModel though, but that's because I tend to have one VM per View, rather than one VM per model. Just different approaches :)

(3) Have a look at C# naming standards, and stop naming class properties with an underscore separating the parts. That may be your Sql standard, but once it has become an object property it is no longer a sql thing so can be named however you like.

Comment: Yes, EF is good. but his 2 questions are more about the the View and data binding. View first or not, really depends.

Comment: It was unclear actually - his use of the word 'layout' seems to have been clarified to mean 'approach', so not just about the view. But rather about whether his approach is correct. And I'd say that no, his approach to how he retrieves data and populates properties for binding is definitely not optimal!

Comment: Thanks guys - lots of food for thought - very much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, makes more now.

Answer (score 1):

The layout/view really depends on your need, that's the beauty of databinding.

If you have 50 fields, but your user only cares about 2, then you just need to present the data of the 2 fields.

For better looking views, you could use the designers, **Blend** for example, to create complex layout and animations.

Comment: Thanks again - there could be up to 50 fields on the one form,so I'm just asking if the method that I have used in this example, would also be the right approach for 50 fields.

Comment: Basically yes, but some times you will not just show the *raw* data. you will need some string format, value converter, datatemplate. And you will like to have a look at MVVM, I believe after you have some taste with MVVM, you'll know that your Activity object is the VM in your sample.

Comment: No, your approach of using a Reader and populating class properties is not scalable. Sure you can do it, but as you say - when you get to 50 you'll be fed up of this. By the time you get to 1000 your code will be a nightmare. Using something like EntityFramework will turn that code into just a couple of lines `Activity Act = ObjectContext.Activities.Where(x=>x.id.Equals(mySearchedForId))`